# clearing text box in angular 2 is not working

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to implement a reusable search box.

Code is basic, I'm relatively new to angular 2 but have worked with angular 1 for awhile now.

Why is the value not clearing on focus on text box?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'searchbox',
  template: `
    <form id="search" action="/search" method="get" [class.focus]="focus" class="searchbar" autocomplete="off" role="search">
        <i class="fa fa-search search-icon"></i>
        <input (focus)="onFocus()" (focusout)="onFocusOut()" name="q" 
          type="text" [value]="value" [placeholder]="placeholder" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240">
        <button type="submit" class="btn js-search-submit">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </form>

  `,
  styleUrls: [
    './searchbox.component.less'
  ]
})

export class SearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  focus: boolean;

  ngOnInit() { }

  onFocus() {
    this.value = '';
    console.log(this.value);
    this.focus = true;
  }

  onFocusOut() {
    console.log('focus out');
    this.focus = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use two-way binding, with ngModel: http://plnkr.co/edit/afPC8UgdbrPWatJAY298?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [(ngModel)] instead of @Input() for two-way data binding.

```
<input (focus)="onFocus()" (focusout)="onFocusOut()" name="q" 
      type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" [placeholder]="placeholder" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240">

export class SearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  value: string;
  focus: boolean;

  ngOnInit() { }

  onFocus() {
   this.value = null;
   console.log(this.value);
   this.focus = true;
  }

 onFocusOut() {
  console.log('focus out');
  this.focus = false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!!